# The etiquette of tag proliferation

Tags: discussion, tags

My activity here on SO is mostly answering questions pertaining to GPU computing. There aren't many (perhaps 20k in total) and they mostly relate to one or two technologies ([cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda) or [opencl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencl)).

One particular user of these technologies has decided that we need more tags related to these technologies and has set off on a quest to re-tag questions with his newly created tags for extremely minor features of the programming paradigms. So now we have (at least)

- [nvidia-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nvidia-sass)
- [gpu-shared-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu-shared-memory)
- [gpu-constant-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu-constant-memory)
- [gpu-cooperative-groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu-cooperative-groups)
- [gpu-atomics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu-atomics)
- [gpu-local-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu-local-memory)

The last one is particularly egregious, because "local memory" means completely different things in CUDA and OpenCL, so the tag is ambiguous from the get go.

In my opinion these are all meta tags (they have no meaning without the programming technology they pertain to) and it is very unlikely that they will be used often, except by the creator of said tags when he is apparently bored and decides to mass add his tags to historic questions.

What is the consensus on this? What would be the correct course of action if they were to be removed?

Comment: Well, I've always said that if there's another tag that perfectly encapsulates all the relevant meanings of another tag you shouldn't create another tag... but I'm just a meta crazy person.

Comment: Contextual tags are okay, albeit that there isn't much point to adding them after the Q+A is done.  As long as nobody removes the [cuda] or [opencl] tags from such a question then there is no problem.  I don't see that happening.

Comment: Tags are not hashtags @HansPassant, not because a tag may exist it means that it should be used, or that is even useful. Useful tags > everything else.

Comment: The [tag:nvidia-sass] might be helpful, but the others are imho unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. There is no consensus on whether very specific tags of this kind are a good thing, and there are reasonable arguments for both stances. Cf. the discussions in [*Should we synonymize or should we dissociate \[each\], \[foreach\] and \[for-in-loop\]?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365469/2751851) -- should loop tags mirror concrete syntax? -- and [*Merge \[partialfunction\] and \[partial-functions\] tags?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367203/2751851) -- is suggestion #5 in my answer a sensible clean-up move or undue interference in the [scala] tag community?

Comment: Those are not [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). A meta tag describes the _type_ of question being asked (homework, debugging, how-to, difficult, etc). A good tag describes the _content_ of the question being asked.

Comment: You can burninate tags all day, but they're like weeds. If you don't yank them by the roots, they just grow back. So I'm more wondering how this enthusiastic user can be persuaded to slow down before anything else is done.

Comment: I'm more amazed that the tag descriptions are not blatently copied from wikipedia or similar sources.

Comment: OP, You are being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398654/can-i-protect-myself-from-getting-banned-as-a-result-of-1-moderators-downvotes).

Answer (score 5):

I'll play a bit devil's advocate, except for that last tag.

- `nvidia-sass` 
  SASS is a common stand-alone topic on Google, in the sense you could have questions about this even without the CUDA tag at all.  This is useful even if few people use it.
- `gpu-shared-memory` 
  It’s unfortunate that, like the term "Warp" when "wave front" was previously used in academic literature, Nvidia had decided to use different terminology early on.  But since what is called "shared memory" is also analogous in [GLSL compute shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader#Shared_memory_coherency) this also could stay. Just the tag probably needs to be edited to include the fact that `__local` qualifier is what is used in OpenCL to define the same thing. And we've have tags for "gpu-warp" for a while that is kind of prior art to this.
- `gpu-constant-memory` 
  OpenCL offers constant memory with the same meaning as CUDA here. Again, you could argue this should stay.
- `gpu-cooperative-groups` 
  Currently this is an [Nvidia-only interface found in CUDA](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cooperative-groups/). Maybe this tag could go away, but it does happen to be useful for people using CUDA:

  - Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous? Yes
  - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? Yes
  - Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? Yes
  - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? Yes, provided no one else make a cooperative-groups interface with completely different use case.
    cooperative groups is not just a function, but a different way of using kernels embedded into the kernel language itself.
- `gpu-atomics` 
  This is applicable across all modern [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) APIs, and you could be an "expert" in using this even if you've never used the API the question used.
- `gpu-local-memory` 
  This one *does not* help with a lot.  If anything this one should go.   I could see "cuda-local-memory", but anything outside of that is extremely ambiguous. Local is not used the same way in OpenCL, and in Vulkan there is a concept called "device local memory" which could get discombobulated with this.  [This post explains it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297067/in-a-cuda-kernel-how-do-i-store-an-array-in-local-thread-memory), and funnily enough, the user in question has decided to put their tag on this question as well... You cannot interface or "program" with local memory. It’s automatically used by your GPU, and you only have an indirect control over whether or not it gets used. I find the usefulness of such a tag to be basically zero.

Answer (score 1):

The `gpu-shared-memory` tag in particular is an important disambiguation from the `shared-memory` tag which is to this day often used by questions about CUDA shared memory. According to the tag wiki for `shared-memory`, it is about

> Memory that may be simultaneously accessed by multiple programs

Following this description I would argue that questions tagged `cuda` and `shared-memory` should be about e.g. communicating addresses to global memory between programs/processes or maybe similar topics around unified memory, unified addressing, etc. like e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18597954/10107454), if at all.

If there is some other broad tag concerning fast scratchpad memory outside of GPU computing to use instead of `gpu-shared-memory`, I have not found it.