# How to encourage more (and better) questions for niche communities

Tags: discussion

## As a user, I need consistent standards

I have asked 24 questions. While the majority of my questions seem to meet the community standard, questions in one fairly niche community [CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda) have mostly received one downvote, sat idle, and then been deleted by the community bot.

```
| Tag      | Deleted | Asked |
|----------|-----------------|
| CUDA     | 5       | 7     |
| non-CUDA | 2       | 17    |
```

## I want to get better

You can view all of my [deleted questions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iK9Je8GEqKiF_xxkfH1F2BWURrYxsTyLA3v1xq42U8c/edit?usp=sharing). If they are really worth deleting please tell me. I want to benefit Stack Overflow with good questions. But if my questions in other communities are fine, and the ones in CUDA need to be deleted, I have no way of knowing how to write better questions without some feedback.

I should also note that my CUDA questions came earlier and I have learned to write better questions since then. I continue to try and improve my question writing ability. However, there also seems to be a different standard built into the CUDA community by virtue of it being a smaller community. Because all CUDA questions attract less attention, one downvote carries significantly more weight than it would in a larger community.

-- I have received some feedback as people have looked at my deleted questions. Thank you.

## Encouraging new questions

In my two years on Stack Overflow, I have found it to be a mostly welcoming community. I very much understand the need to remove low quality questions and answers. There are obvious questions that do not benefit the community. There are aspects of my own questions that are not helpful. As I've written more questions, I believe I have gotten better at writing. I want to keep improving. I would also like to see Stack Overflow be a place where asking questions in a niche community is encouraged rather than discouraged. I have been saved in my programming many times because someone one S.O. asked a random, hyper specific question addressing a weird obscure problem I was also having. There is almost nowhere else for these questions to live. I would like to see a slightly gentler standard for deletion in communities where there is little traffic.

Asking a python question that gets no attention and asking a CUDA question that gets no attention are very different things. A question ban is a high toll to pay for asking questions in a less popular topic.

I understand that as a new programmer, some of my questions will seem obvious to the experienced programmers. In one of my first questions, I was floundering for days looking for a solution to a problem. When you're new, sometimes you don't even know the right question to ask. Eventually I wrote a question on Stack Overflow. It was solved with a single comment from a user telling me of a function I had been unaware of which did exactly what I needed. Yes, users should RTFM before asking a question. But as a new user, there was no way for me to comprehend all the available functions inside the Thrust and CUDA libraries to know that function was there. I had searched for it, but what was obvious to an experienced user was completely lost on me until I was led to that particular function. That question was downvoted and deleted. But I believe it had valuable information in the question and answer. The next new programmer who is stuck like I was might have found that. Now, instead, he will be stuck searching.

I believe Stack Overflow should be a place where if a community has little traffic, we should be more encouraging of questions, not more harsh.

## Gratitude

I want to make it abundantly clear. I have found invaluable answers in the CUDA community of Stack Overflow. I cannot count the number of times I have tried to read something in the manual, been uterly confused, and instead found a clear explanation on S.O. CUDA. There are two users on there in particular who have provided the lions share of useful answers. I am in their debt for sharing their expertise.

However, they in particular are now mostly concerned with answering only the more intricate, interesting questions. That is fine. They are under no obligation to help entry level CUDA programmers find their way. I would however like to see questions allowed to stay for a little bit longer so that the users who might be able and interested in answering will have a chance. With less traffic in that community, it will take longer than in more popular communities.

## Proposal

If a tag has significantly less traffic than other tags, allow a question to stay on there for longer than 30 days before being deleted.

If a question is deleted because of a lack of interest, but its in a tag that is not heavily trafficed, don't count that towards a question ban for the user.

Maybe question bans could be tag specific. If my questions aren't good enough for CUDA, ban my questions there rather than across all of Stack Overflow.

## CUDA Questions

-- Not Deleted --
[Price Floors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316660/can-i-find-price-floors-and-ceilings-with-cuda)
[Cuda Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58088387/cuda-memory-consumed-when-leaving-function)

-- Deleted --
[Sequential Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638889/removing-sequential-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-thrustvector)
[Device Vector Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864477/find-index-of-a-list-of-numbers-in-a-device-vector)
[Asyncronicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563176/does-the-host-wait-for-the-device-to-complete-functions-before-moving-on)
[Copy multiple vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731832/can-i-copy-multiple-sections-of-a-host-vector-to-a-device-vector-in-one-call)
[Track spliced 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524699/how-can-i-keep-track-of-end-points-in-a-flattened-2d-array)

-- Deleted Linux Question --
[RescueTime as service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616272/trying-to-run-rescuetime-as-a-service-failed-with-result-exit-code)

## Edit:

1. Adding links to deleted questions
2. In my first draft, I let my personal frustration seep into the question which was not beneficial to the discussion. I have re-written the bulk of the question to try and be more constructive. My genuine goal is to improve the community. I am sorry I involved personal frustration and assumptions. Thank you to everyone who provided constructive feedback anyway.

Comment: [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) is not a moderator. Moderators are those with ♦s beside their names. Those without ♦s are just regular users.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was unaware of that distinction. Also, I didn't necessarily want to bring attention to a specific person. I don't want to cast dispersion on anyone, and like I said, I've am incredibly grateful for all the contributions he's made. I think the discussion point stands on its own. I only included the quote any my questions because the original version was highly criticized for not having specific examples.

Comment: *I think the discussion point stands on its own* It does, I know of at least one other tag with nearly the exact same issue.

Comment: @John just for your records - you also have [this deleted non cuda Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578803/how-can-i-let-an-admin-account-change-the-prices-on-an-android-ordering-app)

Comment: @JonClements, thank you for bringing that to my attention. I've added the question to the google doc and I've updated the post here. Transparency is of utmost importance to me here. I'm sorry for missing that question in my synopsis.

Comment: ...What action are you classifying as hostile? Downvoting?

Comment: @fbueckert generally cultivating a sub-community of S.O. which discourages new questions because "all the good questions have been asked". Specifically, downvoting because the question is boring, rather than a poorly written question, seems hostile to the S.O. ethos.

Comment: There's a point there, but...I'm not seeing it as hostile.  1) Quality is a subjective determination, and 2) you're premising you know who voted and why.  That's going to be a very high hurdle to prove.

Comment: That is true. I can't know who downvoted or why. I am less concerned with one individual, but more so there seems to be a standard that I am meeting in my general questions, but a different standard for CUDA questions. I'm asking, is there a way to prevent two standards from resulting in a question ban, whether its one individual or the whole niche community. I only point out an individual because he's quoted as holding the mindset I think is unhelpful, and he seems to be the most active influence in the CUDA community.

Comment: The point I'm making is that questions are not automatically deleted the instant they garner a downvote.  They have at least 30 days before the roomba picks them up, and in a low traffic tag, that means there's a better chance it will be seen, and it should be possible to attract an upvote or two in that time, making it immune to automatic cleanup.  I myself have zero experience with CUDA, so I can't say if they're good or not.  But surely there's more than one user actively browsing the tag for good questions.

Comment: @fbueckert is there a way to view deleted posts? I would be interested in doing some data scraping across SO to see if other users are experiencing similar trends. Accepted questions generally, rejected questions from one community.

Comment: Can you please add the links to the deleted questions here? Users with 10k+ rep can see deleted questions.

Comment: I posted a comment under a post by talonmies  to let them know they're being discussed.

Comment: Can you add the post IDs (to the Google Docs document)?

Comment: There are some problem that I noticed in several of your questions: 1) You often explain what you did/tried but do not show the code of that. 2) Some of the question read less like a question but more like a work order. 3) The questions that contain code rarely contain a runable example (includes "...", variables with unclear type, missing declarations, ...)

Comment: This question would likely garner more sympathy if it was written less like a paranoid rant and more of a plea for help. Replacing the mistaken "moderator" with "user" would go a long way, as would the confounding of downvoting with deletion. Anyone with ≥125 rep can downvote; only those with ≥10k (or actual diamond moderators) can vote to delete or delete.

Comment: @BDL Thank you. That is useful feedback and I will absolutely take that into account. I genuinely do want to write better questions, and its been hard to improve without feedback and seemingly inconsistent standards between communities.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, You are right. I let my frustration pour into the question. Originally, another high ranked member wrote a question on my behalf after hearing my story. He tried to leave it impersonal and generic, but without specific examples it was fruitless. With me writing it I did let my personal feelings get mixed into the discussion. I want to improve stack overflow. I want users to not get banned when they (I) genuinely don't understand why questions are only deleted in one community. If that community has low traffic, I want to encourage more questions not less.

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing your question to reflect those desires. On Stack Overflow, questions are living documents; as long as the original theme or intent remains, editing them is encouraged, especially since any comments you make can be deleted at any moment.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I've added links to the questions in the google doc.

Comment: @adiga I've appended the links to the deleted questions to my original question. (they are also in the google doc now)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for your feedback. I have re-written the majority of the question and tried to detach personal rants from constructive discussion.

Comment: @JohnMansell Maybe you could also fix the title which incorrectly says `moderator`? I bet if you would focus the title on how to improve your posts instead of protecting you from downvotes, this post would be much better received and some of the 20 downvotes might be reverted

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you, fixed.

Comment: @francescalus You're right. Forgot to update the total when I was notified of some additional questions. ( didn't realize there were two pages of reputation history)